# How do I store user input in a database?

Tags: asp.net, database, save, user-input

I'm a newbie at this, so please be nice to me =^)

I'm creating a website with ASP.net and I have a sign up page. The user has to enter a name and password in textboxex, and choose a location and reason for joining from dropdown lists. (There is a built in wizard for new user sign-up but I chose not to use it).
I would like to save the information entered in a table in a database in the App_Data folder. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need to learn ADO.NET which is the database access technology of choice for .Net.

Here's a [basic tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/ADODotNet/Lesson01.aspx) to get you started...

Also Googling for [asp.net ado.net tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1CHNB_enUS330US330&q=asp.net+ado.net+tutorial&btnG=Search) will bring up good hits.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a public-facing website, you need to put some serious thought into how you process, store, and retrieve user information. ASP.NET provides a lot of good functionality for this type of thing using the `Membership` class. You'll find this class in the `System.Web.Security` namespace.

You can also use the `aspnet_regsql.exe` application to generate the tables and stored procedures necessary to store this information correctly (i.e. storing hashed values for passwords and secret questions/answers, etc.)

As mentioned previously, many good tutorials (both written and video) can be found on these topics on the [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net) site as well as on MSDN.

As the godfather of ASP.NET, Scott Guthrie, might say: "Hope this helps."

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1) Have a schema representing the database and create it on the machine

2) Have an ability to execute queries against the data

3) Write a query to insert the user data into the database.

I'm sure google has a ton of ASP tutorials.